# SQL count quantity of intervals more than N sec

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know that in SQL (Google Big Query) is a SUM function, but if I need to count intervals. For example,

```
create table BATTLE (battleID VARCHAR(256), countryID VARCHAR(256), yearBATTLE INT);

insert into BATTLE VALUES ('Battle1', 'Country1', 1567);
insert into BATTLE VALUES ('Battle2', 'Country2', 1568);
insert into BATTLE VALUES ('Battle3', 'Country2', 1570);
insert into BATTLE VALUES ('Battle4', 'Country3', 1599);
insert into BATTLE VALUES ('Battle5', 'Country2', 1575);
insert into BATTLE VALUES ('Battle6', 'Country2', 1620);
......
```

I need to find quantity of war, where one war is sequence of battle for one client with intervals less than 10 years.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Data and results in the form of a table would help.  And what is "quantity of war"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  countryID, 
  MIN(yearBATTLE) start, 
  MAX(yearBATTLE) finish,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(battleID, yearBATTLE)) battels
FROM (
  SELECT 
    battleID, countryID, yearBATTLE,
    SUM(delta) OVER(PARTITION BY countryID ORDER BY yearBATTLE) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      battleID, countryID, yearBATTLE, 
      IF(yearBATTLE - IFNULL(LAG(yearBATTLE) OVER(PARTITION BY countryID ORDER BY yearBATTLE), yearBATTLE) <= 10, 0, 1) AS delta
    FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.battle`
  )
)
GROUP BY countryID, grp
ORDER BY countryID, grp
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question (I just changed 10 years to 5 years for the sake of example)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.battle` AS (
  SELECT 'Battle1' battleID,  'Country1' countryID, 1567 yearBATTLE UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Battle2',           'Country2',           1568 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Battle3',           'Country2',           1570 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Battle4',           'Country3',           1599 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Battle5',           'Country2',           1575 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Battle6',           'Country2',           1620 
)
SELECT 
  countryID, 
  MIN(yearBATTLE) start, 
  MAX(yearBATTLE) finish,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(battleID, yearBATTLE)) battels
FROM (
  SELECT 
    battleID, countryID, yearBATTLE,
    SUM(delta) OVER(PARTITION BY countryID ORDER BY yearBATTLE) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      battleID, countryID, yearBATTLE, 
      IF(yearBATTLE - IFNULL(LAG(yearBATTLE) OVER(PARTITION BY countryID ORDER BY yearBATTLE), yearBATTLE) <= 5, 0, 1) AS delta
    FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.battle`
  )
)
GROUP BY countryID, grp
ORDER BY countryID, grp
```

result is as below

```
countryID   start   finish     battels.battleID    battels.yearBATTLE    
Country1    1567    1567       Battle1             1567  
Country2    1568    1575       Battle2             1568  
                               Battle3             1570  
                               Battle5             1575  
Country2    1620    1620       Battle6             1620  
Country3    1599    1599       Battle4             1599
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but if you mean that a war is a sequence of battles then you can get a sequence by joining the table to itself:

```
select  *
from    BATTLE a
join    BATTLE b    on a.countryId = b.countryId
where   abs(a.yearBATTLE - b.yearBATTLE) < 10
and     a.BattleId <> b.battleId
```